# Replace with regular expression in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a dropdown list which displayed in page source:

```
<option value="2" >39</option>
<option value="3" >40</option>
<option value="4" >40.5</option>
<option value="5" >41.5</option>
<option value="6" >42</option>
```

After searching I find the solution to replace the option tags:

Find: `<option[^>]*>([^<]*)</option>`

replace with \1, which result in:

```
39
40
40.5
41.5
42
```

But I also want to remove all the white spaces and new lines, and replace "." with "_", so the output should be 39,40,40_5,41_5,42
Thanks.

Comment: please post real bit of source and real bit of expected result

Comment: if you remove the newlines how will you get the requested output ?

Comment: @aelor I want all in one regex statement, the expected output is 39,40,40_5,41_5,42

Comment: Why one single regex statement? Just do one thing at a time. First your replacement, then `\s*`->`,`, then `\.`->`_`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a way to do the job with an unique regex, but in two passes:

First pass:
Find what: `<option[^>]*>([^<]*)</option>\R`
Replace with: `$1,`

Second pass:
Find what: `\.`
Replace with: `_`